# Обработка кликов в отдельном файле

Tags: android, java

Доброго дня!

На множество Activity нужно подцепить обработчик кликов, код один и тот же. Уже когда есть несколько Activity, редактирование кода этого обработчика на всех Activity занимает много времени.

Не знаете ли способа, как это вынести в другой файл и просто вызывать метод в нужных Activity?

Comment: Listener сделать отдельным классом и назначать его в Activity

Comment: @Suvitruf так и хотел сделать, но этому классу нужно extends Activity ? Потому что без этого не могу воспользоваться findViewById

Answer (score 1):

Создайте базовое активити с этим методом и все эти активити наследуйте от него.